# What happened to Satou at the end of the last episode of season 2?

Tags: ajin-demi-human

My question is, why are there two Satous at the end of the last episode of season 2; and how did the Satou with the cross-shaped scar end up masquerading as an American soldier?

To recap, Satou has his head chopped off, revives, and is then killed again and captured by American soldiers.
While being transported on the American plane, we see that there are actually **two** Satous: one with a cross-shaped scar on his cheek posing as an American soldier, and the real one, imprisoned with Tanaka.

Comment: The one as American soldier is actually the one at the beginning of Season 1 Episode 1, maybe the first captured ajin in the world.

Comment: At the 21:15 mark, Satou says he was having a dream so for now we can only assume it was a simple dream.

Comment: I think Sato was part of the United States Marine Corps in the past that is why he is such well trained.

Comment: See http://ajin.wikia.com/wiki/Sat%C5%8D

Comment: actually blowing up the american plane was satou plan . did you remember the scene when nagai going to bury satou alive , satou activate a bomb detonator that count 1 hour , actually that is bomb on the american plane .

Comment: The young captured soldier wasn't Satou. He was just a random soldier. Satou was a soldier who captured him. The events in Africa took place before Satou realizing he was a Ajin, and his scar is an injury from a past mission which heal after his first death.

Answer (score 2):

There weren't 2 Satou's in there, the one with the scar was Satou in the past. He was dreaming about the time when he was still part of the American military, and captured the first demi-human known. We already knew about this in the earlier episode when the Americans were discussing the email that was sent to them by Nagai who posed as the two Americans sent by the US. Samuel T. O'Brien was the registered name of Satou and you can see the big red stamp of "Dishonorable Discharge". I could guess that he took the "SA" from Samuel, the "T" from his middle initial and the "O" from his last name to form Sato/Satou. This is just my assumption though.

The only ones in the plane are Satou and Tanaka which were placed in an astronaut suit I guess and as we can see there was a slight vibration which Satou felt before the plane exploded. So we can assume that the vibration within Satou was what caused the explosion. We still don't know how Satou did it but it may be planted inside his body but some dismissed the thought because we saw with the fight with Nagai's "flood" and him that his body was completely stabbed and hurt which would cause the possible bomb inside him to explode but if ever he found a way to put a bomb inside him within the time frame of when he was given to the Americans and the time he was transferred to the plane then that might explain it.

As for the scar that was seen in his dream, this might be because of the fact that he already died which then removed his scar completely.

Answer (score 0):

Sato was part of the United States Marine Corps in the past.He was part of an ultra-elite section of the military fighting in Vietnam.

So in last episode we see Sato past as Marine and Sato in present captured by American.

Also See: http://ajin.wikia.com/wiki/Sat%C5%8D

Comment: That's not the part I'm referring to. I'm referring to the two Satous in the military helicopter. One of them is captured, and one of them has a scar on his face and ends up blowing the helicopter to free the other Satou.

Comment: At 20:45 min of Ep 13 Season 2 ?

Comment: I think it's at 21:10.

Comment: i was talking about same part

Answer (score 0):

This is just my opinion though, but I think the captured Ajin in episode 1 was not Sato. I taught the captured Ajin was Sato, but then I saw another soldier who looked like Sato but with a big scar on his face in episode 13 (The scar was there because probably he hasn't revived as Ajin yet). My first taught, that soldier was Sato's father or his grandpa or his relatives or something. But after searching, Sato was one of the US Marine so I thought he was one of those soldiers who captured the first Ajin in episode 1. As for the identity of the captured Ajin, I still have no idea.